# Debugging Electron renderer process with VSCode

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code, electron

I tried this document -- [Electron debugging (main and renderer process)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron) -- but hit a problem.

I went through the guide one by one and it is all fine until *"1. Update the contents of renderer.js to"* in ***"Debugging of the renderer process"*** section.
But when I try *"2. While your debug session is...."*, VSCode shows the image like below and I cannot attach the debugger to the Electron process.

The list in the image shows the tabs of my browser but there's no option corresponding to the electron process launched by the Main debugger.
How do I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had that problem too. It appears, it takes time for Chrome Debugger to attach to the Renderer process. By the time it is connected the scripts inside Renderer have already been executed.

I've solved this issue by delaying the script execution inside `renderer.js`, like this:

```js
async function main() {
  const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron');
  const isDevelopment = require('electron-is-dev');

  console.log(process.env);

  if (isDevelopment) {
    // this is to give Chrome Debugger time to attach to the new window 
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }

  // breakpoints should work from here on,
  // toggle them with F9 or just use 'debugger'
  debugger;

  // ...
}

main().catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  alert(error);
});
```

I have [a customized version](https://github.com/noseratio/electron-quick-start)  of **Minimal Electron Application** which solves this and a few other problems I faced when I started developing with Electron.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @noseratio, the sample worked for me. Sorry for the delay in approving your answer. Indeed, finally I couldn't find how to apply this approach to my project built with react-redux + electron, though I guess the "Main" debug configuration should be changed. I'll try finding a solution for a while or may open a new question.

Comment: @K.Makino, glad if it helped, there's also another approach which is to use Chrome DevTools directly for Renderer scripts (rather than debugging in VSCode).

Comment: Yes I know the alternative, but I prefer to go VSCode since with that during debugging I can easily point out where is the problem.