# Sequential launch in VSCode debugging

Tags: json, reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron

Given answered and solved partially regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844870/debugging-electron-renderer-process-with-vscode/53113300?noredirect=1#comment93406266_53113300), I have now the following launch configurations to debug my react-redux + electron app.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Main",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.js",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "runtimeArgs": [
          "--remote-debugging-port=9229",
          "."
      ],
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "run-script",
          "start"
        ],
        "port": 9229
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Renderer",
        "url": "https://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "runtimeExecutable": "C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera developer/launcher.exe",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "--remote-debugging-port=9229"
      ],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "All",
      "configurations": [
        "Main",
        "NPM",
        "Renderer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So it works as this: the `NPM` configuration starts the node.js server and then `Renderer` and `Main` respectively debugs the front-end part and back-end part.

However, when the compound setting is launched, all of them are executed at one time and both https://localhost:3000/ and election app shows blank screen until the server is completely set up.

For now, it is okay to just reload the webpage and the electron client once the server starts, but I'm just curious if there is a way to make a sequential-launch order to make it further elegant. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make your renderer code a little more elegant by doing an attach instead of a launch.

For example I use a compound where I launch the main, and then attach to the renderer with the following (no reload needed).

```
 {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/src/app",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/src/app/out/**/*.js",
      ],
      "protocol": "inspector",
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Renderer",
      "trace": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "port": 9222,
      "timeout": 60000
    },
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "App Main & Renderer",
      "configurations": [
        "Launch App Main",
        "Attach to App Renderer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I guess a simple attach method would not work. It gives the same problem stated in the previous question (see the link on the first line in my question).

Comment: Huh I don't have that issue. I posted my full configuration above. With this configuration the renderer automatically attaches without the VS code drop down list. The only issue it leaves remaining is that you may miss some breakpoints in constructors in the renderer depending on how long it actually takes to attach

Comment: How do you start the server prior to launching electron and attaching the renderer?

Comment: Electron apps are usually meant to be desktop applications, so I don't setup a server, I just launch my electron application.
In non-debug mode, I would just use 'electron .' to start my application. Maybe you have a more complex setup.

Comment: I see. I created my app by "electronizing" an existing React+Redux app so that it needs a node.js server.